# Отображение html элементов

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка, safari

Проблема: при просмотре с iPhone на Safari `placeholder`'ы `input`'ы в форме съехали вниз.
Изменение/устранение паддингов эффекта дают ровно 0.
Через псевдоэлемент `::placeholder` также ничего не удалось сделать.

Скриншот проблемы: [скриншот](https://prnt.sc/h4ef39)

Comment: задать высоту инпуту и соответствующий line-height, например высота в 40px и `line-height: 40px`, отступы в 0

Comment: Лучше приведите воспроизводимый кусок верстки (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), скриншот ничего не даст для разрешения Вашей проблемы.